# Combine two directories into a virtual directory and bookmark it?

Tags: dired

How can I define two separate directories, create a virtual directory out of them in `dired`, and also bookmark that?  I want to launch the bookmark and get the combined view.

I know [`dired+` has something close](https://superuser.com/a/807979), but as far as I can tell, this gives you a list of directories.  Iwant the *content* of these directories instead.

Answer (score 5):

**A. Wrt the Dired union buffer part of your question:**

Yes, take another look at [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), in particular, **`C-x D`** (command `diredp-dired-union`).

If you have some Dired buffers whose contents you want to combine, say `dirbuf1`, `dirbuf2`, and `dirbuf3`, then use:

```
C-x D my-union-dired-buf RET dirbuf1 RET dirbuf2 RET dirbuf3 RET C-g
```

That is:

- `my-union-dired-buf` to name the Dired buffer to use.  (You can also add the contents of dirs to an existing Dired buffer.)
- `dirbuf1`, `dirbuf2`, and `dirbuf3` to specify the Dired buffers whose contents you want to combine.
- `C-g` to say you're done.

If you do not have existing Dired buffers, and you want to create a Dired buffer whose contents combines the contents of multiple directories, say `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3`, then use a negative prefix arg with `C-x D`:

```
M-- C-x D my-union-dired-buf RET dir1/* RET dir2/* RET C-g
```

That is:

- `M--` to tell `diredp-dired-union` you will specify dirs to include (not necessarily dirs in Dired buffers).
- `my-union-dired-buf` to name the Dired buffer to use.  (You can also add the contents of dirs to an existing Dired buffer.)
- `dir1/*`, `dir2/*`, and `dir3/*` to specify that you want the contents of those directories.  (Specify the directories either relative to the current `default-directory` or as absolute names.)
- `C-g` to say you're done.

In this example, if you used, say, `dir2` instead of `dir2/*` then you would get a Dired buffer with the contents of `dir1` and `dir3` and a single line for directory `dir2/`.  The glob pattern `dir2/*` means all files and subdirectories in directory `dir2` (directly, as children, not recursively, as descendants).

`C-h f diredp-dired-union`:

> diredp-dired-union is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>       `dired+.el`.
>
> It is bound to menu-bar subdir diredp-dired-union, C-x D.
>
> (diredp-dired-union DIRED-NAME DIRBUFS &optional SWITCHES EXTRA)
>
> Create a Dired buffer that is the union of some existing Dired buffers.
>       With a non-negative prefix arg, you are prompted for `ls` switches.
>       With a non-positive prefix arg, you are prompted for file and dir
>       names to add to the listing - see below.
>
> You are prompted for the name of the Dired union buffer.  Completion
>       against names of existing Dired buffers is available, but you can
>       enter any other name to create a new Dired buffer of that name.
>
> If the union buffer name you choose names an existing Dired buffer,
>       then what happens depends on whether that buffer is an ordinary Dired
>       directory listing or a list of arbitrary file names.  That is, it
>       depends on whether `dired-directory` is a directory name or a cons of
>       a Dired buffer name plus file names.
>
> - If the buffer is an ordinary Dired listing, then it is converted to
>       an explicit list of absolute file names, just as if these had been
>       chosen individually.  The existing buffer and window are replaced by
>       new ones that show the explicit listing.  (This replacement is
>       necessary because the list of files contained in an ordinary Dired
>       listing cannot be modified.)
> - If the buffer lists arbitrary file names explicitly, then it is
>       updated to include also the files from any Dired buffers and any
>       additional files that you specify.
>
>   If the union buffer name you choose does not name an existing Dired
>     buffer, then its `default-directory` is the same as the
>     `default-directory` before invoking the command.
>
>   If you use a non-positive prefix arg, then you can next choose
>     additional file and directory names to add to the listing.  Use `C-g`
>     when done choosing them.  Any directory names you choose this way are
>     included as single entries in the listing - the directory contents are
>     not included (these directories are not unioned).
>
>   You are then prompted for the Dired buffers to union.  Use `C-g` when
>     done choosing them.  These Dired listings to union are included in the
>     order that you chose them, and each entry is listed only once in the
>     new Dired buffer.
>
>   The new Dired listing respects the markings, subdirectory insertions,
>     and hidden subdirectories of the selected Dired listings.  However, in
>     case of conflict between marked or unmarked status for the same entry,
>     the entry is marked.  Similarly, in case of conflict over an included
>     subdirectory between it being hidden or shown, it is hidden, but its
>     contained files are also listed.
>
>   From Lisp:
>
>   `DIRED-NAME` is the name of the resulting Dired union buffer.
>
>   `DIRBUFS` is a list of the names of Dired buffers to union.
>
>   `SWITCHES` is a string of `ls` switches.
>
>   `EXTRA` is a list of files & directories to be included in the listing.

**B. Wrt the bookmarking part of your question:**

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can bookmark the result of creating such a Dired buffer (see part **A**), by using a [*function bookmark*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#FunctionSequenceVarlistBookmarks). The function to invoke when the bookmark is "jumped to" would invoke `diredp-dired-union` to accomplish what is described in part **A**.  Just define a function `foo` that invokes `diredp-dired-union` with the proper arguments, and then create a function bookmark that invokes `foo`.

I've added this command to **Bookmark+**, to do what you request:

```el
(defun bmkp-set-dired-bookmark-for-files (bookmark-name dired-name to-add &optional switches msg-p)
  "Create a Dired bookmark for a set of files and directories.
You are prompted for the Dired buffer name and the file or directory
entries to include.  With a prefix arg, you are also prompted for the
`ls' switches.

Use `C-g' when done choosing file and directory names.  Any directory
names you choose this way are included as single entries in the
listing - the directory contents are not included.  To instead include
the contents of a directory, use a glob pattern: put `/*' after the
directory name.

You need library `Dired+' for this command."
  (interactive
   (let* ((_IGNORE             (unless (require 'dired+ nil t)
                                 (error "You need library `Dired+' for this command")))
          (current-prefix-arg  (if current-prefix-arg 0 -1))
          (all                 (diredp-dired-union-interactive-spec
                                "add files/dirs "
                                'NO-DIRED-BUFS
                                'READ-EXTRA-FILES-P)))
     (list (bmkp-completing-read-lax "Bookmark") (nth 0 all) (nth 3 all) (nth 2 all) 'MSG)))
  (bmkp-make-function-bookmark
   bookmark-name
   `(lambda () (diredp-add-to-dired-buffer ',dired-name ',to-add ',switches))
   msg-p))
```

Comment: thx alot drew. part A (`diredp-dired-union`) works great! im still stuck on part B since i dont know how to code (im an academic in the humaneties..thats my excuse at least ;-)). can you show me an example on how to use the `function bookmark` and tie it to the `diredp-dired-union`? thx alot! Z

Comment: OK, I added a command that does this to **Bookmark+**. Copy it from here or get it from the latest [`bookmark+-1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b-1.el).

Comment: this is awesome, thx so much. only 1 tiny issue remains. the doc says: To instead include
the contents of a directory, use a glob pattern: put `/*' after the
directory name. when i do that i get an error when trying to launch the bookmark: `insert-directory: Reading directory: no such file or directory, /home/zeltak/ZH_tmp/*`. any clue? this is the current elisp entry for the bookmark:  https://paste.xinu.at/11K/

Comment: Vanilla Emacs that is not on MS Windows does not use `ls-lisp.el`. Instead, it uses the `ls` that is provided by the OS (e.g. GNU/Linux). The code for `insert-directory` is different. I cannot test on a non-Windows platform. But you can try loading standard library `ls-lisp`, by putting `(require 'ls-lisp)` in your init file. See if that helps. Let me know (see the email contact info in the file header). It might be appropriate to file an Emacs bug/enhancement request for this. Note that `ls-lisp` is better for some things and not as good for other things, compared with built-in `ls`.

Comment: More precisely, `ls-lisp.el` advises `insert-directory` to use `ls-lisp--insert-directory` instead.

Comment: Note that if you load `ls-lisp.el` then you can still control when/where and whether its code is used for inserting a directory, by setting or binding variable `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program`. If that variable is `nil` then it uses the `ls-lisp` code. Otherwise it uses the default (e.g. `ls`) code. You could, e.g., load `ls-lisp` but leave that var non-`nil` and just bind it to `nil` in the lambda in `bmkp-set-dired-bookmark-for-files`. If you confirm what is happening (i.e., that loading `ls-lisp` fixes the problem) then I'll add that `nil` binding to the code.

Comment: ping. Could you please try setting `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` to `nil`, to see if that solves the problem? If it does then I'll adjust the code to take care of this, one way or another.

Comment: sorry for the late response (life work et al ;-)). i did try evaling `(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)` but i still get the error. maybe im doing something wrong. here is my current bookmark: https://paste.xinu.at/5vofqr/. happy to help in anyway you need. best Z

Comment: The bookmark looks fine. (I assume that you loaded library `ls-lisp.el`? If not, you need to do so, and do so before you set that variable.) Please follow up by email (see file header). This is not the place for extended conversation or debugging. Thx. Before fiddling with bookmarking, you need make sure that `diredp-add-to-dired-buffer` is working properly for you. Just load `dired+.el` and `M-x load-library RET ls-lisp RET`, and try `M-x diredp-add-to-dired-buffer`.